# Updating node.js to 0.12 Header errors

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
Error: "name" and "value" are required for setHeader().
    at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:333:11)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:101:14)
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
    at Request.start (/Users/aaa/Desktop/projects/a/node_modules/request/request.js:904:30)
    at Request.end (/Users/aaa/Desktop/projects/a/node_modules/request/request.js:1635:10)
    at end (/Users/aaa/Desktop/projects/a/node_modules/request/request.js:676:14)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/aaa/Desktop/projects/a/node_modules/request/request.js:690:7)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:358:17)
```

I get errors like this after updating to node.js 0.12 in request.

What should I look out for?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
npm update
```

or remove node_modules dir and

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your header values is probably not set (At least was for me)
There was a commit message in 0.11.15 - http: cleanup setHeader()
Might be enforcing empty headers now.